# Need help to compile an objective c program on windows XP

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I am a very new to objective c and start learning I started referring some tutorials and books. One of them is http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_and_using_GNUstep_and_Objective-C_on_Windows

I installed GNUstep on windows as instructed in the tutorial, but when I tried to compile the first program hello.m, it throws error
sh: gnustep-config --objc-flags: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the gnustep-config tool is not in your path.  Fix that, and you'll be fine.

To check your path, type env at the shell prompt. (assuming you're using bash or something here, based on "sh:").